# Can I install Selenium2Library for RobotFramework without installing Python?

Tags: python, jython, robotframework

Can I use Selenium2Library if I only have Jython? That is, I haven't installed Python, and was hoping to get away with not needing it. I've read conflicting information however that jybot CANNOT use selenium2library, and I'll need pybot to use it.

If jybot can't use selenium2Library, is there a way to have jybot call pybot somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So after some reading and trial and error, it IS possible to use Selenium2Library with only Jython AS LONG AS you use jython 2.7+ ... jython 2.5.x is NOT compatible with Selenium2Library.

So you can get away with not using Python at all:

1. Install jython 2.7+
2. Install ez_setup.py
3. Install robot framework
4. Install Selenium2Library.

Comment: How to install jython? I have downloaded "jython-installer-2.7-b1.jar" and "jython-standalone-2.7-b1.jar". Which one is required for RF and Selenium?

Comment: How can I install ez_setup.py?

Comment: @user2027659: Download ez_setup.py from peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py. Then, go to the directory where you kept the downloaded file and execute: jython ez_setup.py